# How to cancel onPress in React Native

Tags: react-native

I have a TouchableHighlight zone in my component.

I would like to trigger `_onPress` method for a quick tap, and `_onLongPress` for a longer tap.
This works, but `_onPress` method is always triggered when I release the tap.

How can I do to trigger only one of these methods depending on short tap or long tap ?

```
class MyClass extends React.Component {
    _onPress = () => {
        console.log("Press")
    }

    _onLongPress = () => {
        console.log("LongPress")
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <TouchableHighlight
                style={styles.touchable}
                underlayColor="white"
                delayPressIn={2000}
                onPress={this._onPress}
                onPressIn={this._onLongPress}
            >
                <View style={styles.box}>
                    <Image style={styles.logo} source={this.state.logo.id} />
                </View>
            </TouchableHighlight>
        )
    }
}
```

Many thanks  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablehighlight#docsNav), you can pass both `onPress` and `onLongPress` props directly to the `TouchableHighlight` component, since it inherits all the props available from `TouchableWithoutFeedback`.

```
<TouchableHighlight
  onPress={this._onPress}
  onLongPress={this._onLongPress}
  delayLongPress={2000}
  ...
>
   ...
</TouchableHighlight >
```

Just one of the two events will be triggered.
[Here](https://snack.expo.io/@milore/long-press-example) you can try an example of what I'm talking about.

Comment: The problem is that onLongPress is triggered when you release the finger. I would like that after 2 seconds, the event id fired even if you still have your finger on the screen (like when you long tap an app icon on iPhone for example)

Comment: Simply add a `delayLongPress` prop to the `TouchableHighlight` and the event will be triggered with that delay. I'll add it to my answer

Answer (score 0):

TouchableHighlight inherits all props from TouchableWithoutFeedback ,rather than using `onPressIn` which you are trying to use in your code, you can use long and short press.
 So whatever you are trying will not work in this case.

> You can use both [TouchableHighlight](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablehighlight)  [TouchableWithoutFeedBack](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback), aa both have the same props.
>  It
>   have both [onLongPress](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback#onlongpress) for long press and [onPress](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback#onpress) for short press funtionality which you can fulfill your requirement.

```
<TouchableHighlight
    style={styles.button}
    onPress={this.onPress}
    onLongPress={this.onPress2}
>
    <Text> Touch Here </Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

and,

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedBack
     style={styles.button}
     onPress={this.onPress}
     onLongPress={this.onPress2}
>
     <Text> Touch Here </Text>
</TouchableWithoutFeedBack>
```

Hope this helps.....Thanks :)

Comment: I think this is incorrect: `TouchableHighlight` inherits all the props from `TouchableWithoutFeedback`, so `onPressIn` is available (note that @Eric wrote it works)

Comment: yeah, i forgot it..Thanks